# react-quill editor in funtional

Tags: reactjs, react-quill

when we paste some text after writing some lines it automatially goes to first line. I want to stop behaviour if I paste something that my cursor should be there only it shoud not go to first line .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpvov.png)

nothing coming to my mind.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.